# How to write Unicode object in excel

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm writing a data frame in excel using group by function. I get an error `AttributeError: 'Unicode' object has no attribute 'to_excel'`.

DataFrame:

```
final_day_wise = daily_sales_data.loc [ : ,
                 ["Placement# Name", "Date", "Delivered Impressions", "Clicks", "CTR", "Conversion", "eCPA", "Spend"] ]
```

Output:

```
startline = len(placement_sales_data) + len(final_adsize) + 18

for placement, placement_df in final_day_wise.groupby('Placement# Name'):
    writing_daily_data = placement.to_excel(self.config.writer, sheet_name="Standard banner({})".format(self.config.IO_ID), encoding='utf-8', startcol=1, startrow=startline, index=True, header=True, merge_cells=False)
    writing_daily_data_new = placement_df.to_excel(self.config.writer, sheet_name="Standard banner({})".format(self.config.IO_ID), startcol=1, startrow=startline + 1, index=False, header=True, merge_cells=False)

    startline += len(placement_df) + 4
```

I'm getting an error while writing placement variable, however, the error is not coming `placement_df`.

Also can I sort the stuff based on index?

Comment: Tabs were messing with formatting a lot, so I tried to clean things up without removing author's intent.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `groupby` on final_day_wise, you are getting a dictionary like object where the key is an item from the column that you grouped on (in your case 'Placement# name') and your value is a groupby object. You are getting an error when you try `placement.to_excel()` because placement is a string, not a dataframe object.

What is it you were expecting `placement` to be?

It is possible to sort by index. For example there is a `df.sort_index`. How do you want to sort by index?

*EDIT:*

based on your comment this is what I think you may be looking for.

```
new_df = placement_df.copy()
new_df.columns = [
    [placement] * len(new_df.columns),
    [col for col in new_df.columns]
]
```

then

```
new_df.to_excel (
    self.config.writer , 
    sheet_name="Standard banner({})".format(
        self.config.IO_ID
    ),
    startcol = 1,
    startrow = startline+1, 
    index = False,
    header = True,
    merge_cells = False)

startline += len(placement_df) + 4
```

Comment: So means I can't put it on excel, is it? so placement is same as (placement# Name). How can i cast placement to data frame. Sorting needs to be done ascending false. so after applying group by, can i apply sort_index?